# developing simple web application using SPRING boot

Tags: java, spring

I am developing a simple web application using Spring boot,
Please find the below code.

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
public class HelloApplication {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }

}
```

when i am trying to Run, i am not getting the option to run.. in run as ..

please find the screen shots [image]

Comment: Run in the Run as... ? in the option Run as... there should be options as: spring boot app, are you entering this menu from the top or clicking right in some file in your application?

Answer (score 0):

Your class should be :

```
@Controller
@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleController {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleController.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping
    @ResponseBody
    String home() {
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```